# Infinite looped vertical slider with no pause

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, infinite-scroll, vertical-scrolling

I wrote a script

```
setInterval(function(){ 
  $('#vslides').animate({
    top: "-=1960"
  }, 60000, function(){                                 
    $('.vslide:last').after($('.vslide:first'));
    $('#vslides').css('top', '0px');
  }); 
}, 60000);
```

It works nice, scrolls the almost `2000px` image in a minute, but, at the end it stops. I need it to continue to the next image (same image, just repeated) and keep going... I have tried several things, but can't seem to get it right. How do I make it continuous, and remove the stop/pause at the end of the interval?

Comment: You have the interval set to only start over every minute.

Comment: correct, so what is the smart alternative?

Comment: I'm writing an answer :)

Comment: Fire the animation again when the first one completes instead of on an interval, probably

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some kind of recursive function. Here's a solution that provides a single function for animating one element, but also accepts a callback function. Then we create a second function that will recursively iterate through all the elements in a wrapped set, call our animating function, and pass in a callback that will increment our index and call our recurse function again to animate the next element.

```
// slides an element
function slideIt($elem, callback) {
  /* begin animation */
  $elem.animate({
    top: "-=1960"
  }, 60000, function () {

    /* animation complete do whatever you need here */

    if (callback) {
      /* a callback was provided, invoke it */
      callback();
    }
  });
}

var $elems = $('.all-my-elements');
var index = 0;

// slides a wrapped set of elements one at a time
function slideRecurse () {
  var $elem = $elems.eq(index);
  slideIt($elems.eq(index), function () {
    /* increment index and call slideRecurse again */
    index++;
    // continue animating indefinitely
    // we're at the end so start over
    if (index === $elems.length) {
      index = 0;
    }
    setTimeout(slideRecurse, 0); // no delay. Just using it to queue up the next call on its own stack.
  });
}

// begin sliding all of my $elems one by one
slideRecurse();
```

Comment: i'm gettting this error...
Uncaught TypeError: $elems.at is not a function

Comment: Sorry, replace all the `.at`s with [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/). I modified the answer.

Comment: [Here's a demo](http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/yNXKMB?editors=101) where I use this answer to fade out, then in all the elements one at a time indefinitely.

Comment: It still pauses at the end of each image. =(

Comment: Can you duplicate your setup in a demo like the one I linked in the above comment? If you can duplicate your animation as you currently have it, I can probably modify it from there. Plus, duplicating it in an isolated environement (outside of your real app) helps isolate the issue a lot

Comment: Aha! I see what you mean. That would be [JQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)'s easing function which by default is set to `"swing"`. Set it to `"linear"` instead. http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/LVLdzj

Comment: Many Thanks! Linear fixed it with the original code as well... I have the code above, as well, and want to learn a little more about Angular... thanks again

Comment: Just be careful about your original code because it's a balance between two separate timeouts. Your interval timeout and your animation timeout. That code will almost certainly end up becoming unstable if you keep building on it :)

Comment: Apologies for my original answer having some angular stuff in it. I was answering two questions at once and forgot yours had no mention of angular.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80324/discussion-between-xeuce-and-chev).