# transform from center of text line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have transform css applied to a line of text (font-size), but it animates from the left side, I want it to animate from the center. I am using Bootstrap framework so the div is vert/horiz centred.

**HTML**

```
<article class="col-md-12">
   <div class="lg-indx-img">
    <a href="..." class="linkage"></a>
    <div class="cat-icn">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
article {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.linkage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.lg-indx-img { padding: 20% 0; }

.cat-icn {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.linkage:hover + .cat-icn {
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

when `.linkage` is hovered the title in `.cat-icn` increases in size. I don't know the length of the text line since it's generated by Wordpress post.

EDIT - The top picture is what it does now, the bottom picture is what I want it to do

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by  "it animates from the left side"?

Comment: the font scales up to 25 px from 15px, but it scales from the top-left of the text line. So it looks like it stretches to the right as it grows

Comment: I'm having a little difficulty understanding the visual effect. Think you could duplicate it [in a demo](http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/LVLdRy)? If you can duplicate the animation as you have it in a demo I might be able to modify the demo to achieve the effect you want. I think that would be easiest if you're up to it.

Comment: unfortunately I can't figure out how to bring in bootstrap framework to jsFiddle, I've updated my post with a graphic whicH i hope will help describe it

Comment: In the link in my comment I provided a demo that already has the code from your question. I've now added bootstrap JS and CSS to it. Here's the link again: http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/LVLdRy

Comment: I don't understand, Can I add to this, I haven't used code pen?. I'll update my code in the post to include the bootstrap (i took it out to make my question easier to understand

Comment: Yes, just click "fork" at the top to create your own pen demo and you can add stuff to it and save. Then just paste the URL of your forked pen when you're done. Check out the comments on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30789666/498624) as the question asker and I are doing exactly what I'm asking you to do here :)

Comment: oh ok, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doRmJJ

Comment: Did you add code to that demo to make it animate the way you're seeing? You can tweak that demo to your heart's content until you have it working the way you describe in your question. I don't see any text being animated at the moment.

Comment: i did, the entire screen is a button basically (because of .linkage)

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the text in the middle. Got it. Give me a minute to take a peek :)

Comment: Check out the answer I left down below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out.

http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/bdRvvJ

```
.linkage:hover + .cat-icn {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(3);
}
```

Instead of animating the font size, animate the `transform` property instead. Then in your hover rule use the `transform` property to adjust the scale of the element.

Comment: the scale feature doesn't work, I am using safari, so I figure there is a cross-browser issue, also is there a way to center the text in the window?

Comment: Ah, no problem. You just need to use `-webkit-transform` property then. [Tested in Safari](http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/NqgYzZ).

Comment: perfect thank you, all I gotta figure out now is how to center it vertically in the window too. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem! Don't hesitate to post another question if you encounter any more snags :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting a new font size, you can try using the `transform` property, which should do the right thing since you have `transform-origin` already set to the center.

```
.linkage:hover + .cat-icn {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Comment: what do I have to change in the .cat-icon css , adding that value doesn't do anything